# Replace regex matches in string

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to replace the value of each match using regex? Something like the below:

```
public static string TestMethod(string source)
{
    var regexToMatch = new Regex("[MY_REGEX_STRING]");

    foreach (Match Id in regexToMatch.Matches(source))
    {
    var newId = GetIdFromSource(source);
    Id.Value = newId;
    }

    return source;
}
```

In my c# code, when a match is found I will be calling off to a method that returns a new id and want to replace the old one with the new one and then return the updated `source`.

I get the correct matches, just don't know how to replace them.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Right now you're trying to assign a value to Id, but it is read only. Can you give us an example input and output ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490061/c-sharp-string-replacement-using-regex

Comment: `GetIdFromSource(source)` would return the same value right!..if so you can do it with one statement i.e `regex.replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to run some code to generate the replacement string for each match. In that case, the Regex Replace method with a MatchEvaluator is what you want. The MatchEvaluator is called for each match and can provide a replacement string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx